# Javascript: Assigning a variable and testing it at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, control-structure

In PHP, we can assign a variable AND test it at the same time:

```
<?php
if ($result = $this->find()) {
    $this->do_something($result);
}

function find() {
   if ($this->day == 'Sunday')
       return '1234';
   else
       return false;
}
```

In the above example, on Sundays, $result is set to '1234' and calls the `do_something` function. On other days, it is set to false and nothing else occurs.

**Is this kind of thing possible with Javascript?**

Comment: Try it and find out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
var day=[
    'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday',
][new Date().getDay()];

if(result = find()){
    do_something(result);
}

function find(){
   if(day == 'Sunday')
       return '1234';
   else
       return false;
}
```

Tada!  Calls `do_something` on Sundays.